# How to return a value from a coroutine from a method that is non suspending?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

What I've tried so far

```
   fun getCPByID(ids: List<Int>): List<CheckingPointVo>  {
        var list : List<CheckingPointVo> = emptyList()
       coroutineScope.launch {
              
           list =  someMethod()
       }
        return list
    }
```

here I tried to use async and await but that cannot be run from a non suspend function. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: u need to have some `notify mechanism` once the job is done, if u want to wait in the same thread till the job succeeds use `coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)`, i would not recommend it though since it would  freeze the UI thread.

Comment: how do I make the said mechanism

Comment: use `liveData` or `flow` or some kind of callback

Comment: thanks I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really with the current structure, you're basically trying to combine synchronous code with async.

You have 3 possible options though to make it async:

1. Use a callback:

```
 fun getCPByID(ids: List<Int>, listCallback: (List<CheckingPointVo>) -> Unit) {
       coroutineScope.launch {      
           listCallback(someMethod())
       }
    }
```

**Note**: If you're using it from Java, this should work with either Java lambdas or `Function`. But you may create an interface for this, like :

```
Interface ListCallback {
    fun onListReceived(list: List<CheckingPointVo>)
}

fun getCPByID(ids: List<Int>, listCallback: ListCallback) {
    .... // Same implementation
 }

// Call it from Java
getCPByID(ids, new ListCallback() {
    void onListReceived(List<CheckingPointVo> list) {
         ...
    }
});
```

2. Use either an observable pattern, use a `Flow` or `LiveData`. A possible example:

```
 fun getCPByID(ids: List<Int>) = coroutineScope.launch {
           flow {
               emit(someMethod())
           }
       }
    }
```

3. Make your function a `suspend` function and use `coroutineScope.launch` from the caller

Comment: seems great but since this function is being called from a java class and I am not familiar with java I cant figure out how to pass the listener in java. from point 1

Comment: Ah, then you could create an interface, I'll update my answer